# Modeling a population over time given certain parameters

Tags: predictive-models, population

I am trying to model a population over a span of time. The span of time is between the birth of the first person and the death of the last one, say the years 1867 and 2151. Total people born is a known number, say 14313. We can assume that the number of people alive at any moment follows a normal distribution. How can we come up with a formula to calculate people alive from this population giving the year as an input? For example, how many people are alive in the year 2000?

Note that in using the numbers given as examples, even in the peak of the distribution, total people alive will be less than the total people born, because the first people will have died and some won't be born yet. We can assume a uniform lifespan of 75 years to simplify.

Thank you!
Frank